# rsync pattern matching names

Tags: regular-expression, rsync

I'd like to rsync a bunch of files and ignore any case, spaces, periods, dashes, or underscore differences in the names when matching what to sync.

So, as an extreme example "TheFilename.zip" would match "__THE- - -File---nam-e...._.zip" (assuming the size and time matched).

I can't think of a way to do this.

Comment: How about using `find` to generate a list of files and pipe that you rsync.

Comment: You can't do that with `rsync`.  `rsync` always assumes source filenames match destination filenames.  The easy workaround would be to normalize filenames on both sides before running `rsync`.  The hard workaround would be to essentially re-implement `rsync` in shell: make a list of files on destination with sizes, timestamps, and checksums, make the same list on source, compare them according to your rules, decide what to sync, then feed the list to `rsync` (or just copy the files by some other means, since it no longer matters at that point).

Comment: I figured it was nigh-impossible. My idea, but it's absurd, is to create MD5 hashes, then manually sync the files to a neutral location, then copy them to the existing filename. I'm not going to do it though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will probably do what you want

```
#!/bin/bash
#
ritem="$1"              # [ user@ ] remotehost : [ / ] remotepath_to_directory
shift

rhost="${ritem/:*}"     # Can be remotehost or user@remotehost
rpath="${ritem/*:}"     # Can be absolute or relative path to a directory

# Get list of files on remote
#
echo "Looking in $rpath on $rhost" >&2
ssh -n "$rhost" find "$rpath" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 |
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' rfile
    do
        rkey=$(printf "%s" "$rfile" | tr -d '[:space:]_. -' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
        list[${rkey/*\/}]="$rfile"
    done


# Get list of files from local and copy to remote
#
ss=0

echo "Considering $*" >&2
for lpath in "$@"
do
    test -f "$lpath" || continue

    lfile="${lpath/*\/}"
    lkey=$(printf "%s" "$lfile" | tr -d '[:space:]_. -' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')

    # Do we have a match in the map
    rfile="${list[$lkey]}"
    test -z "$rfile" && rfile="$lfile"

    # Copy across to the remote system
    echo "Copying $lpath to $rhost:$rpath/$rfile" >&2
    rsync --dry-run -av "$lpath" "$rhost":"$rpath/$rfile" || ss=$((ss+1))
done


# All done. Exit with the number of failed copies
#
exit $ss
```

Example usage

```
375871.sh remotehost:remotepath localpath/*
```

Remove `--dry-run` when you're happy it's working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As Satō Katsura points out in comments, this is impossible to do with `rsync` out of  the box. It is also something that I think `rsync` should not do.

If you are copying *a single file*, and if that filename is available in the variable `name` as `__THE- - -File---nam-e...._.zip`, then you may remove the unwanted characters from the filename and copy the file like this:

```
ext=${name##*.}
shortname=${name%.$ext}

rsync -a "$name" "user@target:${shortname//[-_ .]}.$ext"
```

For `name='__THE- - -File---nam-e...._.zip'`, `$ext` will be `zip` and `$shortname` will be `__THE- - -File---nam-e...._`.

If your shell does not support `${parameter//word}`, then use

```
rsync -a "$name" "user@target:$(printf '%s' "$shortname" | tr -d '-_ .' ).$ext"
```

Both `${shortname//[-_ .]}.$ext` and `$(printf '%s' "$shortname" | tr -d '-_ .' ).$ext` will become `THEFilename.zip`.